# Cannot clean install windows 10, getting weird error(s)

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, ssd

I've "googled" this, error # and message alike. I'm really confuse at what to do...

So got new ssd instead of HDD. I download Windows 10 Education off Microsoft Imagine website: [Concordia University - ECS - Microsoft Imagine Premium](https://e5.onthehub.com/WebStore/OfferingsOfMajorVersionList.aspx?pmv=769faff4-d124-e511-940e-b8ca3a5db7a1&cmi_mnuMain=bdba23cf-e05e-e011-971f-0030487d8897&ws=8f012e89-3370-e011-971f-0030487d8897&vsro=8) which I use the .iso to flash my USB using rufus

And I got the following error if I do automatic install :

> The computer started using the windows installation media. Remove the
>   installation media and restart your computer so that Windows starts
>   normally. Then, insert the installation media and restart the upgrade.
>
> [Do not select | Custom [advanced]| to perform an upgrade.

Now if I did custom install I get the following error: 0x80070570

So, seeing the first error message, I thought that the computer was trying to UPGRADE my "current" version of windows which would obviously fail seeing that I have a blank SSD SO , I found this: [Download Windows 10][3] which gives you the choice of either upgrading the PC or flashing a USB to use on a different PC.

So  I flashed my USB ( AGAIN) and went on to try to install my computer.

Automatic install: same error as the first one

Custom: 0x800750D or something like that ( I'm at work and can't recall the error but it wasn't the same).

I'll point out that I have keys for all of the different version I can install (w7, w8 and w10) ; all from the site onthehub.com. However, the latter only gives upgrade for w7 and w8 ( an SDM and SDX - which I've never dealt with before). So I need an iso for either download and even then, I don't know if it would work seeing all the trouble I'm currently experiencing with Windows 10.

EDIT : Will add a real screenshot when I'm home but seeing as this post will probably get no attention at that time, I'm adding a picture of the exact  same settings I had  (using ISO image however)

I tried using Windows 8.1 Premium installation with my computer and the same error occured ( same settings on rufus):

[image]

Comment: [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10?d2784474-fdb0-4e9d-9e47-5e88c0e053ec=True) only allows you to download `Windows 10 Home` or `Windows 10 Professional`.  You can only download Windows 10 Education from either the the source you were using or Microsoft's Volume Licensing Service Center website.

Comment: "I'm at work and can't recall the error but it wasn't the same" - We need the exact error.  `0x800750D ` is an activation error code, which makes no sense, within the installation environment.

Comment: either way, it still throws an error when trying to install. It didn't ask for the key whatsoever. As for the error I did give one up there even with the EDU install. AND t he message with the automatic. It was one error using  the download from microsoft website.

Comment: It sounds like you used the incorrect Rufus settings in that case.  `0x80070570` error code is connected to Windows Update, which again, does not make sense within the Windows Installation Environment.

Comment: Again, the microsoft tool downloaded in the 2nd link didn't 1)prompt for the key and 2) didn't use rufus for install as it is a download tool ( the link says USB flash tool). If it didn't prompt for the key but the same error occured in automatic install, something's up somewhere but I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: You said you used Rufus: "which I use the .iso to flash my USB using rufus" the second link, as I pointed out once, cannot be used to install Windows 10 Education.  So wipe it from your memory entirely.  This SSD, is the HDD that was installed, appearing in the boot order before or after the flash drive?

Comment: The second link cannot be used to install Windows 10 Education, which you indicated, is the version of Windows 10 you have a license for.  If you want to install Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional then you should edit your question, and make that clear, because its not clear currently. As for access to your other versions of Windows you do have, you can create the bootable image, from the "an SDM and SDX" easily enough but thats a seperate question.

Comment: The issue at hand is not a key working or not. If I flashed an image to my usb, the install should work fine. Now that is out of the way, the errors keep happening whether or not it is the EDU version or home or premium. My key has NOTHING to do with this because my USB drive with premium / home did NOT ( I'll write it again so it's clear) -NOT- require me to enter a key, hence making the error NOT key related

Comment: Also I'll add that the issue is the image or my hardware, I'm trying to pinpoint it using the errors but had no luck on google as all the errors found were about updating to Windows 10, which I'm not doing seeing as my SSD has no OS installed on it

Comment: What settings did you use with Refus exactly?  Update your question, with a screenshot, of the exact settings you used for the Windows 10 Education .ISO you downloaded.

Comment: I understand its not a license problem.  I am trying to explain that, by even trying the second ISO, it wasn't ever going to work.  Can you please show me more respect?  This issue is caused by one of several reasons, I am trying to figure out, which reason actually applies to you.  I have asked several questions, and I still need the answers to them, otherwise I won't be returning to this question.

Comment: 1) added a link I can't add a SS 2) Link holds same settings that I used.  At worse if it doesn't help I'll create a new question later on 3)Explain how it wouldn't work if the USB image was now replaced with a new image that was either home or premium.  4) HDD doesn't appear in boot order, everything in the BIOS seems normal even in the boot order. I'll add that I don't care which version is install on my computer, be it Education / Home / Premium if that's where you were getting at

Comment: If you edit your post and improve the formatting, provide the exact error message, attach screenshots.  I will provide a 150 reptuation bounty on this question when its eligible, open a chat with you, and answer the question.  *I cannot work, and thus will be unable to answer the question, without factual exact information.  *

Comment: "At worse if it doesn't help I'll create a new question later on" - Please Don't do this.  Just improve this question.

Comment: @Ramhound , I added the Screenshot, anything else you need me to add? Also let me say that I also tried Fat32 as a seeting

Comment: Does the download site provide a has for the downloaded files? So you could verify whenever your downloaded files are OK? Is the SSD recognized in the BIOS? What kind of hardware do you have? Are you able to see the disk in windows? (During Setup press Shift+F7 and check with e.g. diskpart). He gave you a pretty complete list of what he expects and even offered to put up a bounty. For one the actual error on the second case is missing.

Comment: I never said he didn't answer. Anyways, yes, SSD is recognized.  And I tried to answer him in my main post to see what was up, thankyou though :)

Comment: Hum I tried Fat32 too and it led to the same error ( so  I tried both of them). And no the system I took a screenshot of is my brother computer. My laptop has nothing on it so I can't get pass BIOS. It needs an OS. ANything else you think could affect the installation?

Comment: Also looking on Crucial website (the SSD maker), it is compatible with my model ( the SSD). So I'm guessing this is an .iso error but even Ubuntu can't be installed on there ( though I know nothing about ubuntu and it's kernel so I'm just looking at a bunch of gibberish). Weird....

Comment: "And no the system I took a screenshot of is my brother computer."  - You never made this known.  **Do you have CSM enabled or disabled?**Anyways, I am starting to lose track of things, you should edit your question.  You don't need to mention when/what you added.  *Your question revision history is clear with regard to that.*  If any information from a comment is important, you should mention that, then delete the comment.  Please don't just copy and paste the comment, actually include the information, in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

`.SDX` and probably `.SDM` files as well are files used by a Microsoft download manager (Secure Download Manager). It should be available as a download from your University site as well.

See also: [Downloading Software from DreamSpark.com with Secure Download Manager](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2013/11/20/downloading-software-from-dreamspark-com-with-secure-download-manager/)

Comment: I did use the .sdx and .sdm but same error happened trying to install windows 8